# Alguien podria explicar este codigo en php?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    require_once 'core/models/class.Autoload.php';
    Autoload::load();
?>
```

descargue un proyecto que me hizo mi programador, y ahora estoy estudiando php para poder rehacerlo yo mismo, lo descargue de amazon, pero nose porque me lo toma con muchos defectos en localhost, se ve que hay algo que no logra cumplir la llamada.

- El error es que me aparece la pagina con el background y las imagenes (la parte del login), pero no me aparece los modulos, ni de registro, ni otros modulos que tenia la web online. por ejemplo, una llamada era asi.

  include_once 'core/modules/side_userbar.php';
  include_once 'core/modules/formation_modal.php';
  include_once 'core/modules/dashboard.php';

Yo le puse para probar, la url completa por ejemplo localhost/folder/folder/core/modules...

** el error que aparece es este;
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_result() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\GMO1\core\models\class.Builder.php:1636 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\GMO1\core\modules\register.php(7): Builder->GetLastWithdrawals() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\GMO1\index.php(89): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\GMO1\core\models\class.Builder.php on line 1636

Comment: Se que como miembro de la comunidad, se debe recomendar a aquellos nuevos usuarios como formular una buena pregunta, pero como no se como enlazar como aquellos otros usuarios lo hacen ese tipo de contenido, entonces resumidamente te dare una recomendación que se puede ver directamente en el manual de este sitio, es proveer de un mayor background a la pregunta, aqui aun no queda claro ni el tipo de error, ni lo que no funciona etc por ejemplo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que si estas obteniendo un error, edites la pregunta y lo pongas, tambien, en caso de que no sea un error si no que simplemente no sepas como poder acceder a localhost y configurarlo de acuerdo a los archivos que tienes para que funcionen, deberas proveer mas información que simplemente: 'lo descargue de amazon', hay muchas variantes aqui.

Comment: Otra recomendación que se hace muy frecuentemente en el sitio es dar un ejemplo minimo y verificable del problema, con el código que haz puesto no es posible saber realmente que esta pasando, es como yo darte una pagina que para funcionar depende del archivo javascript y yo darte solo el html... (obviamente no es necesario mostrar todo el codigo, pero si lo minimo para reproducir lo que estas experimentando), vale :3

Comment: Mira, segun entiendo basicamente lo que deseas es una explicación de ese código nada mas, por lo que segun lo que se de PHP, session_start() cuando se llama lo que permite es iniciar una sesion o crearla y una vez creada, la pagina reconocera en cada una de las vistas donde sea llamada esta función, que quieres usar la sesion actual y recordarla para que persista en otras paginas, ob_start() no me queda claro para que sirve, require_once permite que un archivo solo se cargue una unica vez, (previene que por error sea cargado mas de una vez).

Comment: Autoload::load(), creo que se refiere a un metodo de la clase Autoload importada anteriormente, lo que se intenta es llamarla, creo que precisamente aqui esta el error.

Comment: @Riven muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me convendria eliminar ese codigo entonces?

Comment: Para nada, no te convendria, ya que por algo creo que debe estar ahi, mas bien hay algo que por alguna razón no esta funcionando bien, yo creo que te falta algun modulo o no colocaste alguna cosa donde debia estar... pero es solo una posibilidad...

Comment: @Riven, te invito a leer [¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058/conoces-los-magic-links-para-los-comentarios-aprende-a-usarlos), de esta forma podrás aprender a enlazar hacia las diferentes guías de ayuda. Como por ejemplo, si usas `[ask]` te enlaza a [ask]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias voy a leerlo! :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta reemplazar la linea:

```
Autoload::load();
```

Por:

```
Autoload->load();
```

Si esto no funciona, intenta instanciar primero un objeto de la clase y luego usar su metodo:

```
$autoload = new Autoload();
$autoload->load();
```

O tambien:

```
Autoload->{'load'}();
```

o con la instancia:

```
$autoload->{'load'}();
```

Comment: Si te funciono?? :33